# Best way to detect iphone orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I am making an app where I change the buttons layout depending upon if the user moved his iphone in portrait vs landscape mode. I thought the best place to put my code will be in

```
-(BOOL) shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation
```

But there are two major problems with that

1. When the page is loaded shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation is called at least 3 times. I want to execute my code only once.
2. Even when I move from viewController1 (page1) to viewController2 (page2) with Modal segue and I rotate my iphone on page2 it still calls the autorate code which is in my viewcontroller1. That is very strange.

Anyways, what is the best place to put my orientation based icons in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sole purpose of the method

```
-(BOOL) shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation
```

is to determine which orientations are supported.

If you wish to do custom actions on rotation, then you want to implement one or both of the method

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Comment: ... or `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`, which is often quite useful since any code you place inside that method will (if applicable) animate also.

Comment: I just googled this and apprently I need to add [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(didRotate:)
name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil]; along with didRotate function and in didRotate I will know if the user moved the device in portrait or landscape mode?

Comment: @SamBudda You do not need to register defaults for the methods listed above. However, if you want to have a custom method `didRotate` that is triggered for any device orientation change, then you should add the notification you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create subclass of UIView and override `-(void)layoutSubviews`. This message will call when you change orientation or set `setNeedsToDisplay`. You will get animating changing position for you subviews.

Get current orientation very easy as `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]`

Answer (score 0):

**[`UIDevice.orientation;`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/orientation)**

However, you should still correctly implement the notifications from the rotations of the user. If you want to avoid running your code multiple times unnecessarily, just remember what the last orientation was and only execute your code if it has changed.

Comment: Note that the device orientation is not the same as the interface orientation.